# Teres major pull-ups

Tags: muscle, biomechanics

Since the teres major does most of the actions of the latissimus dorsi, except spinal extension and scapular movement because it is not attached to the spine but to the scapula. I was wondering that if by doing pull ups while holding a constantly retracted scapular position one works more the teres major because the muscle is forced to constantly work in a stretched position. This should make the teres major work more than in normal pull ups.

Does the logic stand true?